# Youtube Data Api v3 - Finding All Channels On Youtube

Tags: c#, json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently tryin to find all active youtube channels day by day.

Forexample:

My Get String is : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2009-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2009-01-02T00%3A00%3A00Z&type=channel&key={API}

It returns me 
totalResults    1000000
resultsPerPage  50

but the problem is when i try to surf on nextPages by pageToken, i only can go for 3 more pages. There have to be more than 150 channels created in a day. I'm %100 sure about it.

Can anyone please help me with a solution or a better string?

Thank you, king regards.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a limit for searches see this filed issue: [issue 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35171641) and [issue 2](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6476&q=Channels.List&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary). I'm not sure if there are any work around regarding this issue.

Comment: i see, but the problem is it doesnt even returns me 10(maks page limit)*50(maks limit for a page)=500. It only returns me 5 results.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&type=channel&publishedAfter=2017-09-18T00:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2017-09-18T00:10:00Z&key={APİ}